# Agda compilation error in the standard library. (Possible archlinux agda bug?)

Tags: haskell, archlinux, agda

I'm compiling following trivial program (`Agda.agda`):

```
module Agda where
  open import IO
  main = run (putStrLn "Hello, World!")
```

with this command: `agda --compile --ghc-flag=-dynamic Agda.agda`. I'm compiling with `-dynamic` since I'm in archlinux so without this flag Haskell can't find any of the standard libraries. This gives me the following error message:

```
Calling: ghc -O -o /storage/src/test/Agda -Werror -dynamic -i/storage/src/test -main-is MAlonzo.Code.Agda /storage/src/test/MAlonzo/Code/Agda.hs --make -fwarn-incomplete-patterns -fno-warn-overlapping-patterns
[60 of 75] Compiling MAlonzo.Code.Algebra.Properties.BooleanAlgebra ( MAlonzo/Code/Algebra/Properties/BooleanAlgebra.hs, MAlonzo/Code/Algebra/Properties/BooleanAlgebra.o )
Compilation error:

MAlonzo/Code/Algebra/Properties/BooleanAlgebra.hs:5278:70: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
     |
5278 |                            (coe MAlonzo.Code.Algebra.d1484 v0 v3 v4) 
     |                                                                      ^
```

This seems to be consistent and I can't compile anything that requires this file of the standard library. I am only using official arch packages and nothing else. How can I fix this issue? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Agda version: 2.5.3

GHC version : 8.2.2

Agda-stdlib : 0.14

Comment: Please add the Agda, standard library and GHC versions.

Comment: @asr edited my question to add that information.

Comment: It seems an error in Arch Linux. Using the same versions in Ubuntu the line 5278 of  `MAlonzo/.../BooleanAlgebra.hs` is `(coe MAlonzo.Code.Algebra.d1484 v0 v3 v4) v5)`

Comment: I think archlinux update agda-2.5.3-6 solved this issue since after that update standard library does compile.

Comment: Good to know. @prover, thanks for sharing!